# iterating one dataframe and using multiple columns of it as criteria to find value in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes Samples and Events

Samples:

```
 ID     Sample_Date
```

0  500001   2021-09-28

1  500002   2021-09-29

2  500003   2021-10-15

Events:

```
  ID     Event_Date  Event
```

0  500001   2021-09-20  BN

1  500001   2021-10-05  BN

2  500003   2021-10-09  AS
...

a desired output example would be:

```
 ID     Sample_Date  last_Event_to_sample
```

0  500001   2021-09-28    2021-09-20

1  500002   2021-09-29    NaN

2  500003   2021-10-15    2021-10-09

Samples has a one to many relationship to Events.

Basicly what i wanted to do is to iterate through each row of the Samples Dataframe and use the ID and the Date as a condition to search for the next smaller date in the Events Dataframe for this ID, in order to create a new column in Samples 'last_Event_to_Sample' .

After two days researching i cannot figure out how to approach this. This is the last step to be finally able to create my plots. I would really appreachiate it ,if someone can help me out!

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you add your expected output to your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) :

```
df_samples["Sample_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_samples["Sample_Date"])
df_events["Event_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_events["Event_Date"])

out = (
        pd.merge_asof(df_samples, df_events,
                      left_on="Sample_Date", right_on="Event_Date",
                      by="ID", direction="backward")
       )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

       ID Sample_Date Event_Date Event
0  500001  2021-09-28 2021-09-20    BN
1  500002  2021-09-29        NaT   NaN
2  500003  2021-10-15 2021-10-09    AS
```

With `direction="nearest"`, we get this :

```
       ID Sample_Date Event_Date Event
0  500001  2021-09-28 2021-10-05    BN
1  500002  2021-09-29        NaT   NaN
2  500003  2021-10-15 2021-10-09    AS
```

And if needed, you can add a tolerance with `tolerance=pd.Timedelta("7d")` (for e.g) as a keyword :

```
       ID Sample_Date Event_Date Event
0  500001  2021-09-28        NaT   NaN
1  500002  2021-09-29        NaT   NaN
2  500003  2021-10-15 2021-10-09    AS
```

*NB : Both dataframes need to be sorted on keys before the merge_asof.*

Comment: I really thank ýou abokey for your response! I integreted your example and checked it, but if there are multiple dates available in Events , it gets the first Date it finds, not the closest to the Sample_Date. I need the last one , something like a max() up to the Sample Date.

Comment: If I can somehow donate you something let me know! I am going to try out to put a lambda expression at the beginning which will contain the date of the sample df and then add a loc() at the end of the group by with the lambda expression and then the first() function.

Comment: No need for that my friend. I'll update my answer to hopefully match your expected output.

Comment: Answer updated, let me know if this handle your usecase.